# Python - save a figure with the same size and setting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I plot figures a lot during my python (through Spyder env.) usage. However, when I try to use `plt.savefig('figure.png')`, the saved figure has a different size from the inline figure plotted on Spyder.

For ex., when I use this command:

```
 plt.savefig('fig1.png')
```

The saved figure looks like this:

[image]

Note that there's something weird with the saved figure, e.g.: the title is cropped, the size is not proportional.

However, the following is the inline figure:
[image]

I tried to modify the size through matplotlib.pyplot documentation but couldn't find such setting. Does anyone know how to save the figure with the exact setting as the inline plot?

Comment: Try `plt.tight_layout()` before saving ([doc for tight layout](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/tight_layout_guide.html))

Comment: @mozway Still doesn't help much, now there is a really big blank space to the right of the figure, but none on the left. And some of the title on the left area is cropped.

Comment: `plt.tight_layout()` works on screen;  `plt.savefig('fig1.png', bbox_inches='tight')` works similarly for saving

Comment: Just to clarify - if you use `%matplotlib inline` which is the default for Jupiter/ipython, by default if does `bbox_inches='tight'` (to everyone's confusion).

Comment: ...also instead of `tight_layout` try `constrained_layout`.  https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/constrainedlayout_guide.html

Comment: Ah I see...thank you very much for the tips guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline figure size plotted in Spyder (or any other IDE or editor) depends on how the editor handles showing figures.

If you want to have an exact size as output of your code, use [`figsize`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) **before** plotting code. (It uses inches)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

# Code to produce figure
```

You can also determine DPI when creating figure or saving.

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=300)

# or

plt.savefig(file_path, dpi=300)
```

Comment: I see that this works....now I can specify the same size when saving...thank you very much @farshad

Comment: @muhammad-rayyan Happy to help. Please consider up voting and/or accepting as answer if it does.